# How to set -moz-transition property from within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to implement

```
-moz-transition: text-shadow 0.25s ease-in-out,font-size 0.25s ease-in-out;
```

property through JavaScript. What is the syntax for that?

Comment: 'Vanilla' JavaScript, or do you have a library available to you?

Answer (score 14):

In raw JavaScript it's:

```
document.getElementById("yourElem").style.MozTransition = "text-shadow 0.25s ease-in-out,font-size 0.25s ease-in-out";
```

Note: A preceding hyphen causes an uppercase letter in JavaScript: `-moz` => `Moz`

Comment: Thnxs 4 helping i will implement this soon

Answer (score 2):

Use `element.style.MozTransition = "text-shadow 0.25s ease-in-out,font-size 0.25s ease-in-out"`.
An example: http://jsfiddle.net/m9Hpc/3/

Comment: thnxs boudou, i will implement it soon.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's **yet another** way to do it that might be of use in some cases:

```
var vendor = detectVendor(); // or hardcode the string "-moz-"
element.style[vendor + "transition"] = "text-shadow 0.25s ease-in-out,font-size 0.25s ease-in-out"
```