# Adding image from pictures through js

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i press the submit button after choosing an image from the first choose file, nothing happens and no image is getting added to the right face of the cube. Under the fuction addphotos(), when i wrote right.style.zoom=2, also it was not working. So i think there is a problem with the function calling or something. 
Code - http://pastebin.com/QCHSH2iy

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var yAngle = 0;
var xAngle = 0;
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {

e = e || window.event;

if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    yAngle = yAngle+5;
    $("section").css("transform",'rotateY('+yAngle+'deg)');
}
if (e.keyCode == '37'){
    yAngle = yAngle-5;
    $("section").css("transform",'rotateY('+yAngle+'deg)');
}
if (e.keyCode == '38'){
    xAngle = xAngle+5;
    $("section").css("transform","rotateX("+xAngle+"deg)");
}
if (e.keyCode == '40'){
    xAngle = xAngle-5;
    $("section").css("transform",'rotateX('+xAngle+'deg)');
}
}
$("#button_left").click(function(){
    yAngle = yAngle-5;
    $("section").css("transform",'rotateY('+yAngle+'deg)');
});

$("#button_right").click(function(){
    yAngle = yAngle+5;
    $("section").css("transform","rotateY("+yAngle+"deg)");
});
$("#button_down").click(function(){
    xAngle = xAngle-5;
    $("section").css("transform",'rotateX('+xAngle+'deg)');
});

$("#button_up").click(function(){
    xAngle = xAngle+5;
    $("section").css("transform","rotateX("+xAngle+"deg)");
});
});
</script>

<style>

.buttons {
align: center;
}
.wrap {
perspective: 800px;
perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cube {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.cube div {
box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(125,125,125,1);
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
.back {
background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}  
.right {
background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
transform-origin: top right;
}
.left {
background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
transform-origin: center left;
}
.top {
background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
transform-origin: top center;
} 
.bottom {
background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.front { 
background: rgba(189,25,400,0.3);
transform: translateZ(100px);
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var zoom=1;
var val;
function zoomings(){
            val=document.getElementById("zooming").value;
            cube.style.zoom=val;
            cube.style.moz.zoom=val;
        }

if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler(), false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler(), false);
} else {
sq.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler());
}


function MouseWheelHandler() {
return function (e) {
    // cross-browser wheel delta
    var e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

    //scrolling down?
    if (delta < 0) {
        if (zoom > 0.3)
        {zoom=zoom-0.05;}
        cube.style.zoom=zoom;
        cube.style.moz.zoom=zoom;           
    }

    //scrolling up?
    if (delta > 0) {
        if (zoom<1.8)
        {zoom=zoom+0.05;}
        cube.style.zoom=zoom;
        cube.style.moz.zoom=zoom;
    }
    return false;
}
}
</script>
<script>
function addphotos() {
right.style.background-image=document.getElementById("image1");
}

</script>
</head>

<body><br>
<div align="center" class="buttons">
<input type="button" value="<--" id="button_left">
<input type="button" value="-->" id="button_right">
<input type="button" value="down" id="button_down">
<input type="button" value="up" id="button_up">

<span>Zoom: </span><select id='zooming' onchange="zoomings()">
    <option value="0.25">25%</option>
    <option value="0.5">50%</option>
    <option value="0.75">75%</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">100%</option>
    <option value="1.5">150%</option>
    <option value="1.75">175%</option>
</select></div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="wrap">
<section class="cube" id="cube">
    <div class="front" id="front"></div>
    <div class="back" id="back"></div>
    <div class="top" id="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom" id="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left" id="left"></div>
    <div class="right" id="right"></div>
</section>
</div>
<div align="left">
<form>
<input type="file" name='image1' id='image1'><br>
<input type="file" name='image2' id='image2'><br>    
<input type="file" name='image3' id='image3'><br>
<input type="file" name='image4' id='image4'><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="addphotos()" value="Submit">           </input>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chances to get a answer are tremendously higher if you put commented code here instead linking to somewhere

Comment: Axel Amthor, done! Do you know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Your chances of getting an answer will also be significantly improved if you trim your code down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) necessary to demonstrate the problem. Your current code contains a lot of excess cruft that I'm fairly sure has nothing to do with the problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the submit button, it does what it should: submit the form. To block it, add `return false;` to `addphotos()`.

There's a really nice plugin for zooming images: https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom Take a look at it!

Also:

1. Sorry, my bad. But you need to read the file's context via the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API, or upload the choosed file. You can't just set the background to the input's value.
2. There is no `el.style.moz.xxx`. See [How to set -moz-transition property from within JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6007595)
3. There is no `el.style.background-image`. What you're doing here: string minus undefined variable. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp
4. Do not use `onclick` attribute. Add an event listener from the JS code.
5. You should use: (weel code block doesn't want to work) `document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false); function MouseWheelHandler() { //...your code }`. Calling a function that returns only one function is not useful.